# why do i get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" , even after clearing my browser cache files?

Tags: php, http, redirect, server

I have hosted my PHP web application in godaddy hosting server.When I load the index page of the web application,i get

> "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

,error message.It doesn't happen all the time,but this error is quite often.After clearing the browser cache it works fine.But why does this error occur? I have searched for this question and solution in StackOverflow,but I am not satisfied with any of the answer.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: check this SO answer. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831152/too-many-redirects)

Comment: Something to look in your code. This normally comes when you have a redirect in an infinite loop.

Comment: I know this problem from password protected sites. The user will be redirected from login.php to home.php if he already has a session. And when you fail with the session check in the home.php you will be redirected to the login. If you clear the cache you aren't logged in anymore

Comment: is the header() in PHP causing the problem ?

Comment: On the start of the index.php page i have only this header code involved <?php if(!empty($session_uid)) { header("location:index.php"); } ?>

Comment: your index php keeps redirecting you to the index.php file when you're logged in. When you aren't logged in you won't be redirected

Answer (score 2):

It's a infinite loop in you application, it keep redirect to current URL, check the code for the loop then it's solved.

Comment: On the start of the index.php page  i have only this header code involved <?php if(!empty($session_uid))
{
header("location:index.php");
} ?>

Comment: $session_uid is not null -> empty($session_uid) == false -> !empty($session_uid) == true -> redirect to index ... that cause the loop, debug the value of $session_uid